# Replace Pattern match with Preferred Text Java

Tags: java

Hey I am trying to replace the a regex pattern in a directory of files and replace with this character 'X'. I started out trying alter one file but that is not working. I cam eup with the following code any help would be appreciated.

My goal is to read all the file content find the regex pattern and replace it.

Also this code is not working it runs but dose nothing to the text file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class DataChange {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

         String absolutePathOne = "C:\\Users\\hoflerj\\Desktop\\After\\test.txt";
         String[] files = { "test.txt" };
         for (String file : files) {
             File f = new File(file);
             String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(absolutePathOne));
             FileUtils.writeStringToFile(f, content.replaceAll("2018(.+)", "X"));
         }
    }
}
```

File Content inside the file is:

> 3-MAAAA2017/2/00346

I am trying to have it read through and replace 2017/2/00346 with XXX's
my goal is to do this for like 3 files at one time also.

Comment: Maybe you are not using correct regex. Did you try running your regex on your text ? Paste your file content.

Comment: I added the information you requested. also i did trying running regex on my test by going to https://regexr.com/ with this regex 2018(.+) it highlighted the text I wanted basically everything behind 2018

Comment: Your file content is "3-MAAAA2017/2/00346 " and your regex is "2018(.+)", so it's no match. You can run your code easily in the debugger and get instant result. You are wasting time here. 
Tips : 
Put a breakpoint on the line where you are writing to file. 
Select the expression that replaces the file content, and inspect the result of the expression.. It takes 2 seconds

Comment: I ment to change the 2017 to 2018 it should be a match after that correct?